# installing cheetah in home directory

Tags: python, templates, cheetah

I am trying to install the Cheetah template engine in my home directory. I have a school website account and do not have root access. I changed my python path to the directory I am installing to, but it tries to put cheetah-compile in /usr/bin which of course I do not have permissions for. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cheetah uses [distutils](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html) for installation, so this is actually a pretty easy problem. After downloading from the Cheetah website, unpacking, and changing into the resultant directory, use

```
python setup.py install --user
```

This will install in a user site-packages directory where you have write privileges. Exactly where depends on your platform, but watch the output and it will tell you.

Another nice side effect is that the user site-package will be in your sys.path, so Python will be able to find it.

Comment: Note that if there is an error message while using it try the following (nothing to add after the =) `python setup.py install --user --prefix=`